# Insert data from a modal form to DB

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add some data to the DB from a modal form in django. After filling all the fields and click on submit it doesn't save on the DB. Here are the models, views and forms and the template. I think the problem it's on the views.py

models.py

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone_numbers = ArrayField(PhoneNumberField())
    industry = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    credit_limit = MoneyField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2,     
    default_currency='MMK', null=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datetime_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py

```
class BuyerCreateView(AtomicMixin, View):
template_name = 'add_buyer_modal.html'

def get(self, request):
    form = BuyerForm()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = BuyerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Buyer created!', extra_tags='alert alert-success')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    messages.error(request, 'Unable create buyer. {}'.format(form.errors), extra_tags='alert alert-danger')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

forms.py

```
class BuyerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Buyer
        fields = ['name', 'phone_numbers', 'industry', 'credit_limit']
```

template

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add-buyer-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">New Buyer</h5>
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" class="close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 modal-body">
            <form id="buyer-form" method="post" class="submit-form" action="{% url 'buyers:add_buyer' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <input autocomplete="false" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating">
                        <label class="control-label">Industry</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input autocomplete="false" type="number" name="industry" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input id="payment-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right submit-button" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', buyers_views.BuyerListView.as_view(), name='buyers_list'),
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9a-f-]+)/$',
    buyers_views.BuyerDetailView.as_view(), name='buyers_detail'),
url(r'^/buyer/add/', buyers_views.BuyerCreateView.as_view(), name='add_buyer'),
```

]

Comment: can you post your *template* `add_buyer_modal.html` as well?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question

Comment: I see that  the form is pointing to `buyers:add_buyer`, are you sure that that url is actually linked to the view?

Comment: Yes.. You can see it on the urls.py that I published now

Comment: I don't think you're rendering a  bound `BuyerForm` on the template. What are the contents of `POST`?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your form is invalid. You only fill out 2 of the 3 fields in the HTML form and send it back to the server. Therefore, when you check to see if the `form.is_valid()`, it's probably returning False and therefore, not actually saving the form.

To check, you can put a print statement inside the if statement printing out 'success' and one after the if statement printing out 'failure'. If you don't see the 'success' print out, it means your form is invalid.

If this truly is the issue, add form fields in the HTML for all fields in your form. Any field you include in the fields attribute of a form by default is required. This means that if the field isn't filled out when calling `is_valid` on the form, a validation error for that field will be thrown.